# Combine latitude and longitude into same column while adding an 'x or y' column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, gis

I have a database that requires input data to be in an atypical format. Normally latitude and longitude would be in separate columns. In this case I need to bring them into the same column and then add an additional column to differentiate coordinate type. I am a python novice so I am in a bit of a bind as to where to start.

I need to get from this:

| Location | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Place1 | 32.123 | 120.123 |
| Place2 | 31.321 | 121.321 |

To this:

| Location | Lat/Long | Coords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Place1 | Latitude | 32.123 |
| Place1 | Longitude | 120.123 |
| Place2 | Latitude | 31.321 |
| Place2 | Longitude | 121.321 |

Edit - This is a simplified example. The data I'm working with has a dozen other columns all of which I would like to preserve, *only* lengthening with the lat/long columns.

My initial thought was to create two exports of dataframe, one where I take the latitude field and one where  I take the longitude field, and then recombine them (duplicating the records), but then calculating the values for the 'Lat/Long' and 'Coords' fields respectively. I do not know a) whether or not this is the right approach or; b) a clean path to get there. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: `df.melt('Location', var_name='Lat/Lon', value_name='Coords')` [melt documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is very close. My example was highly simplified...imagine the original table I have has 10 other columns, all of which I would like to preserve.

Comment: Then set all other col names in a list to the first param: `df.melt(['Location', 'col2', 'col3'] . . . )`

Comment: This seems like it should work but I am getting an error ValueError("arrays must all be same length") so that is a new rabbit hole.